# How do i find out which svn config is currently used on a server?

Tags: svn, svnserve

I have reciently started at a new place, currently wanting to use svn for source code. On the main server we currently have svn installed with several possible svn configs. I am wondering how to find out which svn config is the svn server is currently using? The svn version is 1.4 and it is on enteprise linux 5.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using svnserve and not access over http/apache?

For svnserve, each repository has its own conf/svnserve.conf. So if you've created a repostory with `svnadmin create /var/svn/project1`, then the configuration file will be in `/var/svn/project1/conf/svnserve.conf`.

If you then access the repository with the URL `svn://host.example.com/var/svn/project1`, then **that** config file will be used, and no other. There are no system-wide configuration files for svnserve.